# Modifying Heisenberg's unified field theory with gravity

Tags: gravity, quantum-field-theory

How would Hisenberg's unified field equations be represented if gravity is incorporated. Would it result in a case similar to the Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation, or am I just confused here?

I would really appreciate if the Heisenberg-Ivanenkov equation's essence is explained as there is no firm online source to provide more information.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about physics, not astronomy. It's also on [Physics Stack Exchange](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286507/modifying-heisenbergs-unified-field-theory-with-gravity), by the way.

Comment: @HDE226868 Why do all the courses(graduate level) in astronomy have QFT as a separate subject; hence my question.

Comment: Just because you have to take a course in Field Y to obtain a degree in Field X does not mean that Field Y is a subset of Field X. For instance, many undergraduate chemistry majors may have to take some sort of physics course, yet physics is not a subset of chemistry

Comment: @HDE 226868 ok I do not wish to take this further, I just asked the question hoping that someone would know something about this and provide me some useful info. I had posted this question parallelly on physics SE as well, but did not get any response. Hence, all I wanted by posting this is some knowledge about this not-so-easiy-available topic. If you wish to vote to close, please do go ahead as it's a  democracy and you have the right to do that and I'm thankful that you're letting me know before hand.